# How to destructure props in Vue just like {...props} in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In React I can destructure props like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const myProp = {
    cx: '50%',
    cy: '50%',
    r: '45%',
    'stroke-width': '10%'
  }
  return ( 
    <svg>
      <circle {...myProp}> </circle>
    </svg>
  )
}
```

How can I do the same in Vue? My current verbose version in VueJS is like:

```js
<svg>
  <circle :cx="circle.cx" :cy="circle.cy" :r="circle.r" :stroke-width="circle.strokeWidth"> </circle>
</svg>

computed: {
  circle() {
    return {
      cx: '50%',
      cy: '50%',
      r: '45%',
      strokeWidth: '10%'
    }
  }
}
```

Runable code snippet in React: https://jsfiddle.net/as0p2hgw/
Runable code snippet in Vue: https://jsfiddle.net/zsd42uve/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add to CMS answer, as this doesn't work (completely) with the given example as 'stroke-width' isn't correctly passed (stroke width needs to be kebab-case). For this to work it needs to be:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<script>
  Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: `
      <svg>
        <circle v-bind="circle"> </circle>
      </svg>
    `,
    computed: {
      circle() {
        return {
          cx: '50%',
          cy: '50%',
          r: '45%',
          'stroke-width': '10%'
        }
      }
    }
  })

  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Correct! Thank you for the additional useful information!!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `v-bind` directive to bind all the properties of an object as props:

```
<svg>
  <circle v-bind="circle"> </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I was wondering a little bit how to get the data in child component after deconstructing with `v-bind`, I will share it here.

Parent

```
<template>
  <circle v-bind="myProp" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          myProp : {
                cx: '50%',
                cy: '50%',
                r: '45%',
                strokeWidth: '10%'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

circle.vue

```
<template>

</template>
<script>

export default {
  props: {
    cx: String,
    cy: String,
    r: String,
    strokeWidth: String,
  }
}
</script>
```